# How to change status bar to light mode under min API 21

Tags: android, android-statusbar

In default, android using the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` theme and the status bar text is white, how to change it to black?

Answer (score 1):

actually you could change the color of statusbar for Api >= 19

inside the style of value-v19 put :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="MaterialDrawerTheme.Light">
                <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
                <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
                <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
                .....
        </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mohosyny for advising to introduce the material theme, I fix my problem by using the below AppTheme.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```